# Render multi-array in TWIG

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I post next to my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31454793/symfony2-table-with-3-entity-in-twig)

Because I can't render my array in Twig.

A {{ dump(besoins) }} give me something like

```
 array (size=30)   0 => 
     array (size=3)
       'stock' => 
         object(TG\ComptaBundle\Entity\Stock)[1097]
           private 'dimensions' => 
             object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[1131]
               ...
           private 'id' => int 1
           private 'name' => string 'Dilite 2' (length=8)
           private 'prix' => int 15
       'dimension' => 
         object(TG\ComptaBundle\Entity\Dimension)[1134]
           private 'stocks' => 
             object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[1123]
               ...
           private 'id' => int 10
           private 'name' => string '15 x 15' (length=7)
           private 'longueur' => int 15
           private 'largeur' => int 15
       'besoin' => 
         array (size=1)
           0 => 
             object(TG\ComptaBundle\Entity\Besoin)[1773]
               ...
```

So I can see that I have "besoin" in my array.

But with my twig code, my cells stay empty ... :(

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                    {% for dimension in dimensionslist %}
                        <th>{{ dimension.name }}</th>
                    {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                {% for stock in materiauxlist %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ stock.name }}</td>
                        {% set newArray = [] %}
                        {% for tableau in besoins %}
                            {% if tableau.stock.name == stock.name %}
                                {% set newArray = newArray|merge([tableau]) %}
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% for tableau in newArray %}
                                {% if besoin %}
                                    <td>{{ besoin.nombre }}</td>
                                {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is my Controller :

```
public function commandeAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $materiauxlist = $em->getRepository('TGComptaBundle:Stock')->findAll();
        $dimensionslist = $em->getRepository('TGComptaBundle:Dimension')->findAll();
        $tab1 = array_merge($materiauxlist, $dimensionslist);
        $besoins = array();

        foreach ($materiauxlist as $stock) {
                foreach ($dimensionslist as $dimension) {
                    $besoin = $em->getRepository('TGComptaBundle:Besoin')->findBy(array('stock' => $stock, 'dimension' => $dimension), null, 1);
                    $tableau = array('stock' => $stock, 'dimension' => $dimension, 'besoin' => $besoin);
                    $besoins[] = $tableau;
                }
        }

        return $this->render('TGProdBundle:Projet:stocks.html.twig', array(
                'materiauxlist' => $materiauxlist,
                'dimensionslist' => $dimensionslist,
                'besoin' => $besoin,
                'tableau' => $tableau,
                'besoins' => $besoins));
    }
```

Please can someone help me ?

Comment: Are you sure that $besoin is évaluated to true in twig `{% if besoin %}` ?

Comment: No that's the point, it's evaluated to false I think but I don't know why cause I can see values in my dump

Comment: No, you said you dump besoinS, so this is not related with besoin (without S)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is wrong:

```
{% for tableau in newArray %}
   {% if besoin %}
      <td>{{ besoin.nombre }}</td>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Edit:** it should look like:

```
{% for values in newArray %}
   {% for key,value in values %}
      {% if key == "besoin" %}
         {% for bison in value %}
            <td>{{ bison.nombre }}</td>
         {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thx but sadly "Key "nombre" for array with keys "stock, dimension, besoin" does not exist in TGProdBundle:Projet:stocks.html.twig at line 31". If I put {{ value.besoin }} instead I have an error arraytoString conversion :/

Comment: `{% if tableau.besoin|first %}`

Comment: This is because Bisons is a collection

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure to understand where you want I put this :s

Comment: just replace the first block I quoted from your code with the second code block I´ve posted

Comment: Method "nombre" for object "TG\ComptaBundle\Entity\Stock" does not exist in TGProdBundle:Projet:stocks.html.twig at line 32. I think it takes the first key (stock) in $tableau and not the key $besoin :'(

Comment: If I change my array like $tableau = array('besoin' => $besoin, 'stock' => $stock, 'dimension' => $dimension); error says "Key "nombre" for array with keys "0" does not exist in TGProdBundle:Projet:stocks.html.twig at line 32"

Comment: I have updated the loop structure please try this one

Comment: Key "nombre" for array with keys "0" does not exist in TGProdBundle:Projet:stocks.html.twig at line 32

Comment: I have updated the solution.... but just a hint use the twig function "dump()" in order to debug variables so you can analyse your problem

Comment: I gave you the dump(besoins) at top of my initial post, it seems good. Your last code seems to be better. I'll try to arrange it and come back for tell you how result is ;) Thx a lot for help

Comment: The problem is I have besoin in first column and not in the right one. You can see it here : http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=910438Capture.jpg

Comment: Maybe if I find a solution for put a "X" in <td> when besoin is null it can be good

Comment: Great it works fine with a {% if value %} loop ;) Thx again for you help it was priceless after few days on the same problem !

Comment: Sorry I start here and I haven't reflex ! But I did it now ;)